# Telerik RadHtmlChart Y Axis labels as seconds but showing time

Tags: c#, datatable, telerik

I have a line graph

The Y axis are time in seconds.

[image]

What I want is the legend for each point to be time not seconds

```
lineSeries1.TooltipsAppearance.DataFormatString = "{0}";
```

its just coming up with numbers though :(

also is there any way of formatting the Y axis, so that instead of seconds I get

5:00
10:00
15:00
20:00
25:00

etc ? which relates to

500 seconds
1000 seconds
1500 seconds
2000 seconds

etc

The data is fed in using a datatable in code behind so dont really want to hard code the times as they could be very variable.

```
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            CategorySeriesItem item1 = new CategorySeriesItem();
            item1.Y = int.Parse(row["TimeInSeconds"].ToString());
            lineSeries1.SeriesItems.Add(item1);
        }
```

This draws the point, but what I want to be able to do is set the legends and labels for the time

Answer (score 0):

Set the `BaseUnit` of the `XAxis` to `seconds`: http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/htmlchart/functionality/axes/date-axis#category-series-area-bar-candlestick-column-line

Also, use the `XAxis.LabelsAppearence.DataFormatString` property as you would on the server to get seconds, something like

```
                <XAxis BaseUnit="seconds">
                    <LabelsAppearance DataFormatString="ss">
                    </LabelsAppearance>
                </XAxis>
```